# Error with formatting a date when using addhours()

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm using Powershell v2 to add hours to a date, but I always get an error.

This code below work fine:

```
 $date = Get-Date -format "yyyyMMddhhmmss"
 $DateStr ='{0:yyyyMMddhhmmss}' -f $Date
 Write-Host  $date
```

But when I use `addhours()`:

```
$oriDate=(Get-Date).addhours(1)
$date = $oriDate -format "yyyyMMddhhmmss"
$DateStr ='{0:yyyyMMddhhmmss}' -f $Date
Write-Host  $date
```

I get the error:

> You must provide a value expression on the right-hand side of the '-f' operator.

Comment: Any reason you're not upgrading your version of Powershell? PS v2 is ancient and you'll find the newer versions have some useful functionality that you're lacking.

Comment: i thinks it's my company rule , i'll try persuade my company later then, thanks for the recomendation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a simpler way to get what you're after. Check out the [Get-Date reference page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-date) for examples and generally useful info.

```
(Get-Date).ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmss")

$((Get-Date).AddHours(1)).ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmss")
```

Comment: i use tostring before and get error, overload or something i forgot, so i thought the ps ver 2 not support this and i took different approach, thanks bro it works :)